# Invalid Argument foreach() google api

Tags: php, wordpress, google-maps-api-3

I am using wordpress and I am trying to display the distance between two postcodes. I had this working however it has suddenly stopped and I am not sure why as I have not changed the code at all.

I don't think I have missed anything in the below code?

The error is:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /single-project.php on line 135

The code is:

```
<?php
$my_custom_field = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'app_collection-postcode', true);
$my_custom_field2 = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'app_delivery-postcode', true);
//**Get rid of any spaces either side**
            $my_custom_field_trim = trim($my_custom_field);
            $my_custom_field_trim2 = trim($my_custom_field2);
$url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=$my_custom_field_trim&destinations=$my_custom_field_trim2&units=imperial&mode=driving&language=en-EN&sensor=false";
$data = @file_get_contents($url);
$result = json_decode($data, true);
foreach($result['rows'] as $distance) { 
    echo '' . $distance['elements'][0]['distance']['text'] . ' (' . $distance['elements'][0]['duration']['text'] . ' in current traffic)';
}
 ?>
```

Comment: `echo $data;` `var_dump($result);`

Comment: `var_dump($result)` and whatever result it gives, please post here ..

Comment: Most likely $result['rows'] either doesn't exist, or is not an array. Please print the value as asked before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically your code should work, as long as the supplied origins/destinations doesn't contain characters which needs to be urlencoded.

When it contains such characters(for example UK-postcodes usually contain whitespaces ) you must encode these parameters:

```
$url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?"
        .http_build_query(array('origins'      => $my_custom_field_trim,
                                'destinations' => $my_custom_field_trim2,
                                'units'        => 'imperial',
                                'mode'         => 'driving',
                                'language'     => 'en-EN'));
```

However, for development you should remove the `@` before `file_get_contents` to  get the error-message (if any).